# После ajax не работаюет <script>

Tags: javascript, ajax

Помогите мне пожалуйста. Подобные вопросы уже читал но не смог разобраться в чём дело.
Сам скрипт который загружает страницы в div с id printResult:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startAjax(url){
    
     $('#printResult').html('ghfghgfh');

  var request;
  cache: false;  
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if(window.ActiveXObject){
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
  } else {
      return;
  }
 
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        switch (request.readyState) {

          case 4:{

           if(request.status==200){  
 document.getElementById("printResult").innerHTML =' '+request.responseText+'  ';
 

                     }else if(request.status==404){
        relogin(onSuccess);
    }
           
            break
            }
        }      
    }
    request.open ('GET', url, true);
    request.send ('');

  }
  function print_console(text){
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += text;
  }
</script>
```

А вот в самих страницах есть скрипты и пути к js файлам которые не работают, даже если файлы js ставить вне div.
Например содержание страницы к примеру такое:

```
<link href="./vendor/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Mutiple select list (hold shift to select more than one):</label>
                                            <select multiple class="form-control default-select" id="sel2">
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>3</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

    <script src="./vendor/global/global.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./vendor/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/deznav-init.js"></script>
```

Думал что не совпадают пути .js и .css , но оказалось не то..
Или еще проще:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Ok!'); 
  </script>
```

И он не срабатывает..

Помогите пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сможете выполнить скрипты через `innerHTML`.
Возможные варианты:

- Использовать JQuery: `$('#printResult').html(request.responseText)`
- Написать свою функцию для поиска скриптов в responseText и добавления  в DOM или выполнения кода (`eval()`)
- Разделить/структурировать загрузку HTML и скриптов. На мой взгляд, это более правильный с точки зрения архитектуры приложения вариант.